# How to dynamically pass condition of if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am in a situation where I'll get comparison string in a variable, and I want to use that variable in IF

```
$xyz = '$abc<200'; // Dummy Dynamic Text

if($xyz) { // It should execute like if($abc<200)
    echo 'you are dynamic';
}
```

In the example above the comparison string coming dynamically in $xyz variable and I want to put that variable in if condition, How do I do that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question, explaining _why_ you're in this situation and what you're actually trying to do. Blindly evaluating strings as fragments of code is usually a pretty bad idea.

Comment: 1. What is the output of: `var_dump($abc);` 2. There is nothing dynamic on this you just assign a value to a variable ?!

Comment: `$xyz = '$abc<200';` this is just dummy text, Actually I want to pass whole condition dynamically. Because condition is going to change every time.

Comment: So you want to be able to parse the expression in your if statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use quotes as it is making the string out of it. Do it this way:

```
$xyz=($abc<200); //or, as well, $xyz=$abc<200
if($xyz) { 
    echo 'you are dynamic'; 
}
```

If however you want to keep that condition text in string, you could use eval:

```
$xyz='$abc<200';
if(eval("return $xyz;")) { 
    echo 'you are dynamic'; 
}
```

Comment: it must work, if $abc < 200 - have you checked what value is in your $abc variable?

Comment: `$xyz = ($abc<200)?1:0;` can you check with this ?

Comment: @itssajan you can, but this just changes value of `$xyz` from `true` to `1` and from `false` to `0`, which checked with `if($xyz)` will yield the same result

Comment: @n-dru , You are right, but according to your way $ xyz will just contain true or false. So the statement will be formed like`if(true)` or `if(false)` which I dont want, I want `if($abc<200)`

Comment: @MujahedAKAS Oh, now I understand what you mean! See my edited answer, it works!

Comment: But why did you used return here
`$xyz='$abc<200';
if(eval("return $xyz;")) { 
    echo 'you are dynamic'; 
}`
This Code works...

Comment: from Manual: "eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned."

Comment: before using `eval()` you need to sanitize user input to prevent your application from security attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Eval is sometimes disabled. This is for security reasons. Often with suhosin. Eval can be evil! Think about code injections.

You could try to use an anonymous function.

```
<?php

$func = function($abc) {
  return $abc<200;
};


if ($func($abc)) {
   // great
}
```